# Check if user has an item purchased without using NSUserDefaults or restoring transactions?

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, storekit

I've just started working with Storekit API. Just managed to get through to retrieving a product list and purchasing a product.

However, now I'm trying to figure out how to verify that a player has purchased an item without resorting to reading NSUserDefaults or restoring transactions. Is there any way to actually do that?

Comment: Why don't you want to read NSUserDefaults?You want to know some data without reading it?)

Comment: I think this is more of a question of moving away from storing data in NSUserDefaults because it can be easily accessed and manipulated from various 3rd party programs out there.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to `NSUserDefaults` is a CoreData database, and it comes with all the access-time perks and whatnot.  Since SKProducts aren't serializable, you'll have to come up with some other representation of the data to store (probably the product IDs, they're guaranteed to be unique).

This is also cached on-disk, so there's no network latency when restoring, and there's no requirement for your user to re-authenticate when the restore operation is requested.